# enumerating files recursively in windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I want to enumerate files/folders other than the Knownfolders. I have chosen the folder to enumerate using the Folder Picker.
I would like to know if there is an API which will give me all the files in that folder recursively. 
I will let you know what I have tried, FYI I am choosing "C:\" from the Folder picker:
  I wrote a recursive async function to parse every folder for the files. Although the function being async , it blocks the UI and is taking lot of time.
I tried the Queryoptions to get the files recursively(as provided in the Folder enumeration sample) but that did not return me anything. It returned "0" files.
Please help me with this.

Comment: If your function is run asynchronously it would not block the UI.

Comment: First and most important: to make it async won't let your UI free, it'll **block when data will be needed** so if you query results just after the first cal...(but here I guess because I don't see your code). Second: threads with such I/O operations aren't the _best_ solution (and it's even hard to measure because it varies). I would use just one (background) thread with a queue of folders to "explore"; it'll finally notify UI when it's completed (same as WinForms BackgroundWorker).